# "illegal indirection" looping through a map in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map <int, int> Mymap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        Mymap.insert(i, i);
    }
    for (auto const &t : Mymap)
        std::cout << t.first << " " << t.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xtree(1376,36): error C2100: illegal indirection`

I'm using c++14 with visual studio community 2019

Also, is this the best way of looping through a map in C++?

Comment: `Mymap.insert(i, i);` is wrong because there are no [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) that takes key and value as arguments.

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: You probably want `Mymap[i]= i;`

Comment: `Mymap.insert(i, i);` => `Mymap.insert({i, i});`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: Fixed it by changing Mymap.insert(i, i); to Mymap.insert(std::make_pair(i, i)); Thanks @MikeCAT

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: @connor you can also use `mymap.emplace(i, i)`